# Recyclerview null with Firebaseui

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I trie to retrive data from RealtimeDatabse with FirebaseUI RecyclerView but nothing appears. I tried a lot of tutorials and searched a lot but nothing will help me. I want to retrieve the status from "Parcare2" in a Text view.
The MainAcvitiy where RecyclerView is:

```
public class Parcare extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recview;
    ArrayList<Model_parcare> model_parcares;
   Adapter_parcare adapter_parcare;
    DatabaseReference mref;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;


    String a;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);


        Log.d("opx", String.valueOf(mref));
        recview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recview);
        mref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PARCARE");
        mref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String name=snapshot.child("LOC").getValue().toString();
                a=name;

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference().child("Parcare2").child("status");
       query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String name=snapshot.getValue().toString();
                a=name;
                Log.d("pore",name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model_parcare> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model_parcare>()
                        .setQuery(query, Model_parcare.class)
                        .build();
    Log.d("pte",query.toString());

        adapter_parcare=new Adapter_parcare(options);
        recview.setAdapter(adapter_parcare);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter_parcare.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter_parcare.stopListening();
    }


    }
```

The RecyclerView adapter:

```
    public class Adapter_parcare  extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model_parcare,Adapter_parcare.myviewholder>{


    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public Adapter_parcare(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model_parcare> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Model_parcare model) {
holder.textView.setText(model.getStare());
Log.d("wes",holder.textView.toString());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_parcare,parent,false);
      return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.stare_loc);
            Log.d("lkj",textView.toString());

        }
    } }
```

The model class:

```
public class Model_parcare {
   public String stare;
Model_parcare(){

}
public Model_parcare(String stare) {
    this.stare = stare;

}

public String getStare() {
    return stare;
}
```

}
My xml where data are stored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>







    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

> 

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stare_loc"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="53dp"
                android:text="Stare"

                android:textColor="#FFE933"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and the xml for recyvlerview:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"

android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my Firebase looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The first step is to stop ignoring possible errors. At its minimum `onCancelled` should look like this: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { throw error.toException(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second: there is a single value under `/Parcare2/status`, but you're trying to show it in a recycler view, which is designed to show a list of items. The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is made to deal with a list of nodes, not a singl value as you have here.

A simple way to get it working is:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Parcare2");
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model_parcare> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<String>()
                .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<String>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public String parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        return snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    }
                }))
                .build();
adapter_parcare=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(options);
recview.setAdapter(adapter_parcare);
```

With this code, the adapter will show the value of each property under `Parcare2`. So with the JSON in the question, it'll just show one item "ocupat", but you can add more properties and they'll show up.